# decrease the tappable area of a Rectangle SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

How is it possible to decrease the area where the user can tap on a Rectangle with rounded Corners. When im tapping at the Position of the image, then there will be a reaction although i dont want it.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var x = false
    var body: some View {
        Rectangle()
            .frame(width: 100, height: 100, alignment: .center)
            .cornerRadius(x ? 10.0 : 35.0).animation(Animation.easeOut(duration: 0.4).delay(0.3))
            .foregroundColor(x ? Color.blue : Color.red).animation(Animation.easeIn(duration: 0.1).delay(0))
            .onTapGesture {
                x = !x
            }
    }
}
```

[image: Picture]

Comment: This is an issue with SwiftUI there are [several questions about it in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=swiftui+tappable+area) (in both directions) you will find a bunch of workarounds